# Why can the definition of the following class can access the private data members of another object of the same class?

Tags: c#

Why can the definition of the following class can access the **private** data members `other._name` and `other._id` of **another object** of the same class?

Thanks.

```
public class MyData : IEquatable<MyData>
{

    private long _id;
    private string _name;

    public bool Equals(MyData other)
    {
        bool ret =
            string.Equals(_name, other._name) &&
            long.Equals(_id, other._id);

        return ret;
    }

}
```

Comment: Because accessibility modifiers apply to the type, not the object.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't understand. can you give examples?

Comment: Well, your question *is* an example, really :). `private` annotates a member as inaccessible *from outside of `MyData`*. `Equals` is still within `MyData`, so it has access to `MyData._name` and `MyData._id` at all times. The current instance is irrelevant

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the documentation for [`private`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe.aspx) you see this :

> The private keyword is a member access modifier. Private access is the least permissive access level. Private members are accessible only within the body of the class or the struct in which they are declared, as in this example:

LIke the example above, you are accessing those private members WITHIN that class. It doesnt matter that it is of another instance, you are still in the body of the class and therefore have access to everything.